# Пользовательский интерфейс между игроками

Tags: node.js, javascript, интерфейс

начал изучать ноду, вот пишу свою первую игру, это шашки.

У меня есть 2 функции (на клиенте), 1 функция рисует поле, вторая функция рисует шашки, исходя из их координат.

Так вот когда играют 2 пользователя все выглядит одинаково, тоесть: черные вверху, белые внизу.
К примеру если я играю белыми это очень удобно, но сопернику, который играет черными это таки очень не удобно.

Есть есть ли идеи как можно разворачивать доску для пользователя, который играет черными шашками ?

**Сервер присылает:**

---

```
    return {
        "white": {
            "P": 
                ["5.0","5.2","5.4","5.6",
                 "6.1","6.3","6.5","6.7",
                 "7.0","7.2","7.4","7.6"],
            "K": 
                [],
        },
        "black": {
            "P": 
                ["0.1","0.3","0.5","0.7",
                 "1.0","1.2","1.4","1.6",
                 "2.1","2.3","2.5","2.7"],
            "K": 
                [],
        }
    };
```

Это координаты, где находится какая пешка исходя из типа дамка или пешка.

Пользователи получают координаты и клиент рисует:

**Клиент:**

---

```
/**
*  Игровое поле 
*/
board: function() 
{
   // ID для генерации поля 
   var board_id = "#board";

   for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
   {
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        {
            var coord = i + '.' + j;

            if ((i%2==0 && j%2==0)|| (i%2!=0 && j%2!=0))
            {
                $(board_id).append('<div class="cell cell_white" data-item="cell" data-coord="'+coord+'">'+coord+'</div>');
            }
            else 
            {
                $(board_id).append('<div class="cell cell_black" data-item="cell" data-coord="'+coord+'">'+coord+'</div>');
            }
        }
    }
},


/**
*  Разложить шашки
*/
expanded: function(coordChecker) 
{

    $('[data-item="cell"]').find($('.checker')).remove();


    var checkers_coords = coordChecker;

    for (var checkerColor in checkers_coords) 
    {
        var checkers = checkers_coords[checkerColor];

        // тип шашки [дамка или пешка]
        for (var checkerType in checkers) 
        {
            // координаты шашки
            var checkersCoord = checkers[checkerType];

            checkersCoord.forEach(function(checkerCoord) 
            {
                if(checkerColor == 'white')
                {
                    if(checkerType == 'K')
                    {
                        console.log('Белая дамка');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('[data-item="cell"][data-coord="'+checkerCoord+'"]').html('<div class="checker ck_white" data-item="checker" data-checker="white" data-coord="'+checkerCoord+'"></div>');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(checkerType == 'K')
                    {
                        console.log('Черная дамка');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('[data-item="cell"][data-coord="'+checkerCoord+'"]').html('<div class="checker ck_black" data-item="checker" data-checker="black" data-coord="'+checkerCoord+'"></div>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

---

**Вот так выглядят координаты:**

[image]

Comment: рисуйте на клиенте шашки игрока всегда внизу, делов-то...

Comment: Шашки рисуются исходя из координат присланных сервером

Comment: Вам нужно тогда запоминать не координаты относительно пикселей, а координаты относительно игровой доски.

Comment: честно говоря Вас не совсем понял, добавил реализацию к вопросу

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223 ну так переверните в уме вашу шахматную доску)) Что поменяется? Координаты станут наоборот. Как бы начинайте рисовать не с начала координат, а с конца.

Comment: та вот с php сложно такую логику сразу оседлать. А как на счет алгоритма, который посылает координаты на сервер в качестве хода игрока ? 

Получается нужно дважды разворачивать ? При расположении пешек и при отправки данных о коде со стороны черных ?

Answer (score 1):

Я тут набросал свое видение решения вашей проблемы.

[image: img]

Comment: это в любом случае нужно переворачивать для черных доску, а при отправке координат на сервер от черных, переворачивать их обратно ?